# Steal keyboard events from a window (C API)

Tags: x11, xlib

I'm writing a script for a game (DotA 2 - Invoker) so that for example when I press <kbd>1</kbd> it would steal it and instead send the keyboard events <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> sequentially, so the game shouldn't receive the key event <kbd>1</kbd>.

```
XGrabKeyboard(display, Dota2Win, False, GrabModeSync, GrabModeSync, CurrentTime);
```

I can't achieve that with something like this, because the game still receives <kbd>1</kbd> before `XSendEvent` <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>:

I think `xlib` is unable to do what I want so the only way I can think of is to poll the device directly (`/dev/input/event1` or something), if so, then please show me an example.

(Also, I need C API solutions. so, no python please.)

Comment: You are likely to need XGrabKey, not XGrabKeyboard (which probably fails in your code, otherwise you woud have been locked out of keyboard).

Comment: @n.m. Yes, thanks. it somehow worked with these params: `XGrabKey(display, XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_e), AnyModifier, Dota2Win, True, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync); /* grab 'e' */`